# How do I make a WPF layout Grid fill all available vertical space?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, stackpanel

I have a form with two `Grid` elements in a vertical `StackPanel`. I would have imagined the bottom `Grid` would automatically fill all available space, as I wish it to, but I have set heights on the `Grid` rows:

```
<RowDefinition Height="20" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="25" />
```

The short rows at the top and bottom are for labels and buttons, respectively. I have tried setting the grid's `VerticallAllignment` to `Stretch`, to no avail.

How do I anchor the bottom of the bottom grid to the bottom of the form, regardless of the form's height?

Comment: A vertical StackPanel never resizes its children vertically. Use an outer Grid with two rows or a DockPanel instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you can't use StackPanel to fill all available vertical space.

But you may use a DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <Grid />
</DockPanel>
```

You may also use a Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `LastChildFill="True"` is the default, so it isn't necessary to set it explicitly.

Comment: That combination of `"Auto"` and `"*"` was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!